# How to change environment when logging with sentry

Tags: react-native, expo, sentry

I'm using sentry with react native. I can set the environment when I init:

```
    const env = 'staging'
    Sentry.init({
        environment: env,
        dsn: 'blah',
        enableInExpoDevelopment: true
   
    });
```

But if I want to change the environment later? Do I need to call init again? Or is this something that can be passed up per event?

For capturing events I use something like:

```
    Sentry.Native.captureMessage(eventName, context)
```

Answer (score -1):

You only need to initialize Sentry one time.

When pushing your changes to main branch, don't forget to also change Sentry's environment to "production" and also your app's version, that will help you debug which version is having issues.

Comment: Is it possible to change the environment dynamically? Any issues calling init a second time to change environment? The use case is that I have a way on the login screen to change where the app connects to. It can connect to a production API or a staging API. So it can change in runtime.

Comment: @JoshuaAugustinus It is not recommended to do that because Sentry should be started as early as possible in your application's lifecycle. You can change the env dynamically if you want but if a bug arises, there is a change, Sentry might not catch it and provide full crash logs.